# liberalis corporis et sanguinis christi... liberalis?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin

I've come across an unusual use of "liberalis", and I wonder how it should be translated.  It's in a Catholic catechism, which heads one section:

"liberalis corporis et sanguinis christi domini alimenta sustentabatur"

Here's the full link:

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EinUusNBq-YC&lpg=RA1-PA97&ots=FuOUp4Pwbc&dq=%22%20liberalis%20corporis%22&pg=RA1-PA97#v=onepage&q&f=false

Any opinions on what it means here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A clue is in the next line:

> S[anctus] Liberalis Attinensis Episcopus, Heliodori discipulus…
>   *Saint Liberalis of Altinum, the Bishop and a student of Heliodorus…*

In other words, "Liberalis" is [the name of a saint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalis_of_Treviso).

So I'd translate your sentence something like:

> [Sanctus] Liberalis corporis & sanguinis Christi Domini alimenta sustentabatur.
>   *[Saint] Liberalis was sustained by the nourishment of the body and blood of Christ the Lord.*

According to the stories, Liberalis fasted extensively as a form of mortification (refusing to eat or drink except on Sundays); I assume that's what's being referenced here.

Comment: So is there a feminine word *alimenta* in post-classical Latin? Or is there some kind of post-classical deponent *sustentor*? I do think your translation is the meaning intended by the author.

Comment: @Cerberus Possibly _sustentor, sustentari_, meaning something like "take sustenance from"? Often in later Latin the cases don't seem to line up and I have to force them a bit to get something grammatical; I assume that's just my limited understanding.

Comment: No, I have seen the same thing. For example, *per* + ablative is very common in post-classical Latin. So it could be an combination of soloecisms in this case.